# Python IDLE not executing "for loop" print statements

Tags: python

Can someone tell me why the simple "words" for loop shown below, and others like it (all of them copied from Python.org), didn't print in IDLE when I ran the print statements? When the print statement below and the others tested were run in the Python 2.7.12 shell, the function merely skipped to the next blank indented line without printing anything. (I tried running the print line both with and without indentation and parentheses.)

```
>>> words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
>>> for w in words:
    print w, len(w)
```

Comment: Just hit `enter` one more time so it knows your code is complete and execution starts.

Comment: By the way, IDLE is pretty bad, and you shouldn't use it. For example, IDLE's weird prompt quirks are why your indentation looks wrong, which has prompted 3 answers telling you to fix your indentation.

Comment: @user2357112 Plus one genius closed this as duplicate of an indentation question. I disagree, though, I like IDLE, use it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation! 4 spaces in the next line after the for loop!

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']

>>> for w in words:
...     print w
...
cat
window
defenestrate
>>>
```

Comment: It **is** indented properly. How do you not see the four spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Fix your indentation like so:

```
words = ['cat','window','defenstrate']
for w in words:
     print(w, len(w))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a tab after any for loop.

```
words = ['cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']

for w in words:
    print w, len(w)
```

Your code works fine.

Comment: Thanks Nick, and thanks also to @Stefan Pochmann, for your quick response. The principal error I was making was that I was unaware the return key on the keyboard had to be tapped twice rather than once to run the print statement.